# Basic Bing Silverlight Control ASP.NET C# Example

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, bing-maps

How do I add simple "pushpins" or other objects to a Bing Maps Silverlight Control from the ASP.NET C# code behind? I have only found examples for modifying the actual Silverlight control (i.e. MainPage.xaml). This is not the answer I am looking for. Thanks for the help, completely new to Bing Maps.

Answer (score 2):

MainPage.xaml is not the actual Silverlight control.

See all the tutorials [here](http://pietschsoft.com/?tag=/bingmaps), starting with the 'getting started' samples and working your way upwards. Also see the rest of that blog, quite interesting stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already completed the first tutorial to get everything setup. Then, I added the control to a separate web application and now what I am trying to accomplish is to add dynamic pushpins into the map from the ASP.NET side. For example, I have a search page, that returns a list of "Classes" to a DataGrid. I want to use the same datasource/search to then display those class locations on the Silverlight control.

Comment: You can't access the internals of Silverlight from the outside without some set-up. You'll need to program the control to accept your specific inputs and do the actual work, which means Silverlight programming.